# Pull to refresh in Swift JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, pull-to-refresh

I have my json file in the web, and I'm retrieving the data to my app from there. My app is about countries, so when I add a new country in my json file, I want to go to my app and when I pull I want to show all the counties AND THE NEW country I have created in my json file.

I have added the UIRefreshControl() to my app but it doesn´t refresh and also the "loading icon" never goes away. Here ia an image:

[the "loading icon" never disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNhn9.png)

How can I do that when I create a new country in my json file (for example: England) I pull the screen in my app, and then I have in my App all the countries + England. And make the "loading icon" disappear when all the countries were loaded in the app.

Please help me with this. Thank you very much!

Here is my `UIRefreshControl` code:

---

```
import UIKit

class TableController: UITableViewController {

var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()

var refresh = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    get_data_from_url("https://mylink")

    refresh.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray

    self.tableView.addSubview(refresh)

}
```

---

Comment: You have to add a selector where you have to call `endRefreshing` for `UIRefreshControl`

Comment: Hi Rajan, where do I have to add the selector? The endRefreshing sould be call when all the data in my json file were loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:-

```
   import UIKit

    class TableController: UITableViewController {

    var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()

    var refresh = UIRefreshControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        refresh.tintColor = UIColor.darkGray
        refresh.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.tableView.addSubview(refresh)

    }

    func refresh(sender:AnyObject) {
       // Code to refresh table view  
       get_data_from_url("https://mylink") //Call this on different thread and put the below two lines in completion handler of same thread
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
      }     
 }
```

Comment: you should have called reload data whenever the response of the API come

Comment: Still no effect as API is called on main thread. You just grabbed the main thread and reloaded the table which was the same as the earlier code.

Comment: Hi Sharpkits, can I share with you my code (project) so you can help me with this. I have tried the code you send me, but It doesn´t work, maybe I'm doing something wrong. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari: Please read again carefully, as i've already commented here that call this on a different thread. Read and comment..

Cheers!!

Comment: @Sharpkits Why don't you use the same dispatch background thread and update the UI on main thread rather than commenting in code "Call this on different thread...". That will make things even better

Comment: @Sharpkits can you give an email so I can send you my project? Thanks a lot for your time and answer.

Comment: @Mario Please send it to tech@sharpkits.com

Comment: @Mario: Have fixed the issue and sent you the code. Enjoy..
Cheers!

Comment: @Sharpkits thanks for your answer. I replied your mail.

Comment: @Mario now that your query is resolved. Please upvote and accept the answer.. Thanks! :)

Working on your enhanced requirement..

Comment: @Sharpkits that's for sure I'll upvote and accept the answer. You have helped me a lot. I sent you a message about duplicated rows and when I change the name. Could you please reply my message? Thank you so much!